# Right hand speakers swapped since iTunes 12.2 install

Tags: windows-7, audio, itunes

Yesterday earlier in the day I was listening to music and everything was as normal.

Later on I decided to update iTunes and then a little later noticed that I couldn't seem to hear sound coming out of the right hand speaker, but I had the window open as it is on the right hand side I just assumed that the wind coming through the window was drowning out the sound however it has not been as hot today and so earlier on I did not have the window open and still no sound was coming from the speaker.

So I got on the floor and looked round the back of the PC to make sure every jack was in the correct socket, and yes they are.

What is strange is that the stereo pair is one jack, and the rears are a different one, and the subwoofer and center share a jack together.

So it might make sense if rear left and right sounded the front left and right, and visa versa, but Front Right and Rear Right being swapped is very strange.

Clicking on the left speaker in the (windows) speaker configuration window correctly sounds the left, and the center correctly sounds the center, and the sub does make the appropriate boom noise when clicked.

Does anyone know how to fix the, is the configuration stored in the registry?

Comment: So, the channels aren't swapped at all… simply, one has stopped working. Start from there. Swap the cables & see which works.

Comment: No the channels are swapped, click on Right speaker and the Right Rear sounds, click on the Right Rear and the right sounds.  I was just saying that clicking the left does indeed sound the left